# Adding ViewModel class adds codefirst model to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I need a view-model in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, but when I added one to the models folder, a new entity was added to the database and I was forced to add a migration and update my database. I do not want this to happen, as it is a view-model I am adding and not a model I need to persist back to the database. I want to scaffold some of the controller and views so I have added a primary key to the class. I did not add the newly created view-model to my `DbContext` class.

ViewModel:

```
    public class RolesViewModel 
    { 
        public int RolesViewModelId { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; } 
    }
```

Is there a way to create a view-model that doesn't automatically get added to the `DbContext` class, and therefore cause the data model to change?

Many thanks,

Jason.

Comment: Thats weird. Did you actually add a DbSet<> into your context? Could you please post your ViewModel class and your context?

Comment: He wrote - "I did not add the newly created view-model to my DbContext class.". But I'm agree it's weird.

Comment: public class RolesViewModel
    {
        public int RolesViewModelId { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Are you sure that there are not any pre-build tools that makes changes in DbContext file? It's unusual behaviour to change DbContext automaticly.

Comment: Daniel Grankin, I read that as well, but we need to make sure. Jason, please give us as much information as you can. DbContext, 3rd party packages you've installed. Everything you can think of, that remotly could cause this issue. The ViewModel you've posted looks good as it is, but it is giving us not enough information.

Comment: I've striped it all out now and reverted to a previous migration. I'll take another look and get back soon. I only asked because I have a need for several more view models and didn't want my DbContext changed without me wanting it.

Comment: What if you add the viewmodel to a separate viewmodels folder? Like @DanielGrankin mentioned, there might be pre-build tools at play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Scaffolding will add the following code below in your appContext Class

`public DbSet<RolesViewModel> RolesViewModel { get; set; }`

You can still use scaffolding if you wish, however remember to remove that entry and no table will be created by code first. It will keep your database clean.

Answer (score 7):

Whether you call it a view model, an entity, etc. it's just semantics. Everything is just a class, and the context it's used in determines what you refer to it as. In the case of entities, that's adding a reference either explicitly *or implicitly* in your `DbContext`, and that's the only way you'll end up with something added to your database. I emphasized the "or implicitly* part because if any class that *is* referenced in the your `DbContext`, or any class connected to any class referenced there, also references your "view model", it will end up in your database. Entity Framework will automatically follow your class hierarchies and create tables for all relationships, even if you do not reference a particular class in those hierarchies directly in your `DbContext`.

Comment: Chris, if it's just a viewmodel that needs some information from one or model models to make the view easier to use, then how do I stop it from being added to the DbContext? I created a UsersViewModel that simply had a list of all usernames (from Identity) I included an Id property as well. It created this in my DbContext too. I removed it, and the Id field (as well as the Id reference in the views list) and it seems to behave how I want. It just seems counterintuitive to have to do that.  Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: It sounds as though you scaffolded the class in some way, since if you just add a class, Visual Studio doesn't normally add it to your `DbContext` for you, give it an `Id` property, etc. So, if that's the case, I'd recommend just not using a scaffold and just create a new class from scratch. Now, when you scaffold a controller and views based on a view model, the scaffold assumes you're feeding it an entity, so it will create all the views and such as if it's dealing with an entity. Again, the best solution is to just not use the scaffold in these scenarios.